# C++ explicit destructor call through base pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

So I've written my own memory management class.

Essentially it allocates a big block of memory via malloc, then upon request it hands over the memory to the requester in the program (`as you would expect`.)

I've also implemented `templated` allocation and free functions, which explicitly calls the constructor and `destructor` based on the `templatized` class.

The problem, as you might already be realizing, is what about when I attempt to delete through a base pointer?

The `templated` function picks up the base class' type, and thus the base's virtual `destructor` is called, not the correct derived `destructor`.

There doesn't happen to be a placement delete or anything that would function like a regular "delete" command but not attempt to `deallocate` the memory?

Comment: It seem you have no overload of new/delete in your base class

Comment: maybe take a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to just call the destructor, something like:

myObjPtr->~MyClass()

Comment: Yes, I am explicitly calling the destructor, but it's of the base since that's what's being templatized by the pointer that's passed in.  
  
For example:  
class A  
{  
public:  
   virtual ~A();  
};  

class B : public A  
{  
public:  
    ~B() {}  
};  
  
void main(void)  
{  
     void* pMem = malloc(sizeof(B));  
     A *a = new(pMem) B();  
     
     //Suppose we don't explicitly know what's in 'a' at this point.  
     a->~A();  
}  
  
This is obviously an extremely oversimplified example, but you get the point.

Comment: @user3239404 simply: `A* p = new B(); p->~A();` will cause `p->~B()` to be invoked since `~A()` is `virtual`.

Comment: Okay awesome! It seemed like that's how it should be functioning but I was getting a runtime error on the destructor call. Something else must be going awry then. Thanks!